# Get sources.list back to default for ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 17.10

I had ubuntu 17.04 after the upgrade period ended. I could not upgrade to 17.10 because my sources.list was outdated and could not update because it was not maintaned anymore.

Therefore I replaced my sources.list with a copy of one that could function to upgrade the distro. I copied and pasted it. Upgrade to 17.10 went fine.

Nevertheless, this "artificial" sources.list stayed the same. I would like to get it to look like the default sources.list for 17.10, can anyone explain me how I can do this, or at least paste a version for 17.10 so I can manually replace it?

My sources list:

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the  Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe

## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

When I open software & updates, I do not have the option to choose the canonical partner repositories.

[image]

Comment: Open software and updates and change the server. Tip: Do upgrade your Ubuntu to a supported version 18.04 LTS. Since 17.10 will be EOL in 2 months.

Comment: @AmanMittal  but what should I select there? I dont see the usual options and no canonical repositories (I edited the quesiton to include the options)

Comment: go to Ubuntu software and change the server to main server. No need to select anything